# How to show a loading message before filter with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I need to show some "Loading Message" when a filter is about to happen with AngularJS. My filter is fast, so I can't just show it before return the filtered data. My code:

```
.filter('filterName', function () {
    return function (pacotes, escopo) {
        var filtered = [];
        pacotes.forEach(function (pacote) {
            if (condition)
                filtered.push(pacote);
        });

        return filtered;
    }
})
```

What can I do to show some message, div, anything, before return this data?

Comment: If your filter is so fast that you don't want to just display a message before returning data, why display it at all?

Comment: My boss asked for it.
LOL
I said that it wasn't necessary, but bosses are bosses, right?

He wants a "pretty loading gif or something", in his words.

Comment: How and where are you calling this filter

Comment: Well, in that case, the first thing I would do in this filter is show a message. Then put the code where you get the data as well as a snippet to hide your loading message inside of a $timeout function and set it to however long you want the loading message to display.

Comment: `<div class="package col s4" dir-paginate="package in packages | filtroPacotes:this | itemsPerPage: 9">
        {{content_here}}
    </div>`

My `packages` variable comes from $http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your html:

```
<p id="loadingMessage" ng-show="showMessage"></p>
```

Filter:

```
.filter('filterName', function () {
    $scope.showMessage = true;

    $timeout(return function (pacotes, escopo) {
        var filtered = [];
        pacotes.forEach(function (pacote) {
            if (condition)
                filtered.push(pacote);
        });
        $scope.showMessage = false;
        return filtered;
    }, 3000);    
})
```

I was not able to test this since I don't have all of your code. But something like this should work assuming I have the syntax right. You would have to inject $scope and $timeout in the appropriate places for this to work though.

Edit: I just realized escopo likely means scope in another language. Assuming that is true and you are actually passing in the scope, just put escopo where I have $scope.

Comment: user1289451, I have this in my html:
`<loading ng-hide="finalizado"></loading>`
This is my actual filter:

`.filter('filtroPacotes', function ($timeout) {
        return function (pacotes, escopo) {
            var filtrados = [];

            pacotes.forEach(function (pacote) {
                if (condition)
                    filtrados.push(pacote);
            });

            escopo.finalizado = false;
            $timeout(function () {
                escopo.finalizado = true;
            }, 300);

            return filtrados;
        }
    })`

Comment: Is that working? Or do you have a problem with that? You didn't really give me any info to go along with your code...

Comment: It's not working the way it is written. `escopo` is my controller scope, passed this way: `package in packages | filtroPacotes:this`.

But, the line `escopo.finalizado = true` doesn't seem to be aplied to the real controller scope. I tried with `escopo.$apply` but it also didn't work